# Notation for the collection of all probability distributions on a (measurable) space

Tags: probability-theory, notation

Is there a standard notation for "the set of all probability distributions on a measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$"? I have seen $\triangle(X)$ used when $X$ is a finite set endowed with the discrete sigma-field. (Of course, $\triangle(X)$ is rather the set of all functions $p:X\to[0,1]$ s.t. $\sum_{x\in X}p(x) = 1$, which has a bijection with the set of probability distributions on $X$.) Is there such a similarly standard or preferred notation when $X$ is a general measurable space?

Comment: $$\mathcal M_1^+(X,\Sigma)$$

Comment: Liese and Miescke (https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387731933, see for example page 632 in the freely available back matter) use $\mathcal{P}(\Sigma)$, which I've seen used a couple of times. That being said, it has the obvious issue that you need a different notation for powersets (they use $\mathfrak{P}$).